# If two sets are equal, they exist in the same sets and are members of the same sets. How is that allowed if duplicates aren't allowed in a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I ask because I thought sets can't contain two of the same elements.

Comment: Cross-posted.  Also appears as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724036/if-two-sets-are-equal-they-exist-in-the-same-set-how-is-the-axiom-of-extension

Comment: What is the source of the strange phrase "... they exist in the same set".  What do you understand that phrase to mean?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  But it may help to keep in mind that it's not a "rule" that "duplicates aren't allowed"; it's just that set theory has no way to even express that concept.  Given a set $A$ and an element $x$, either $x$ is in $A$ ($x \in A$) or it isn't ($x \notin A$). Set theory only has the $\in$ relation and there is no way to use that to say "$x$ is in $A$ twice".

Comment: @Eric Towers That was an accident

Comment: @AlGJohnston : You are more likely to get relevant answers if your (carefully worded) question appears as the body of your Question and the title merely summarizes it.  You are free to edit this question to improve both its body and its title.

Comment: Also, I'm reading Set Theory by Zaring and 3.3 says if a = b then [a E C if and only if b E C]. This confuses me because it says both a and b which are the same sets are contained in the same set.

Comment: That definition is wrong. I'm very sure you are misreading. It should say $A=B$ if for all sets $x$, $x\in A\text{ if and only if }x\in B$.

Comment: That's the extensionality. What I wrote as 3.3 is based off of extensionality and equality according to Zaring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,\,b$ have the same elements, $a=b$, so $a,\,b$ have the same properties. In particular, $a\in c$ if and only if $b\in c$. But because $a$ and $b$ are two names for the same set, this doesn't mean $a$ is in $c$ twice.

Comment: That's easy to understand when you put it like that. Thank you.